# How to upgrade a single package with ansible?

Tags: debian, ansible

I'm trying to write an ansible playbook which only upgrades the `linux-generic` package but cannot find the magic incantation to get it to actually work. With this play, I get the error `parameters are mutually exclusive: deb|package|upgrade` which google suggests is due to `upgrade: full` is not meant for a single package:

```
  - name: Check if linux-generic is installed
    command: dpkg -l linux-generic
    register: pkg_chk

  - name: update kernel if installed
    when: pkg_chk.rc == 0
    apt:
      update_cache: yes
      autoremove  : yes
      autoclean   : no
      upgrade     : full
      dpkg_options: 'force-confold,force-confdef'
      name        : linux-generic
```

Removing `upgrade: full` runs the play...

```
TASK [update kernel if installed] **********************************************************
ok: [vivaldi.fammed.wisc.edu]
```

But, when I login to the machine and run `aptitude full-upgrade` it shows ansible didn't do anything:

```
# aptitude full-upgrade
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-203{a} linux-headers-4.4.0-203-generic{a}
  linux-image-4.4.0-203-generic{a} linux-modules-4.4.0-203-generic{a}
  linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-203-generic{a}
```

Ok, so I thought I'd just throw the `command:` module at it and use bare `apt` commands but there is some issue with the command string that I have not escaped properly.

```
  - name: upgrade linux-generic
    when: pkg_chk.rc == 0
      command: apt-get install -y --only-upgrade -o Dpkg::Options::='force-confdef' -o Dpkg::Options::='force-confold' linux-generic
      register: install_chk

  - name: autoremove linux-generic
    when: install_chk.rc == 0
      command: apt-get -y autoremove -o Dpkg::Options::='force-confdef' -o Dpkg::Options::='force-confold'
      register: auto_chk
```

which yields this error:

```
Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  mapping values are not allowed in this context
    The error appears to be in '/usr/src/ansible/tests/upgrade-kernel-only.yml': line 24, column 12, but may
    be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
    
    The offending line appears to be:
    
        when: pkg_chk.rc == 0
          command: apt-get install -y --only-upgrade -o Dpkg::Options::='force-confdef' -o Dpkg::Options::='force-confold' linux-generic
               ^ here
```

I've tried escaping the `:` `=` characters, as well as replacing double-quotes and single quotes. Anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: What is this `linux-generic` package? I can't find any such package in Debian. That may have something to do with your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any specific reason why would you not consider the ansible package module e.g.

```
- name: Install linux-generic
  package:
    name: linux-generic
    state: present
```

As far as the ansible error is concerned, you must enclose your command in double quotes since you are using single quotes inside:

```
 - name: upgrade linux-generic
    when: pkg_chk.rc == 0
      command: "apt-get install -y --only-upgrade -o Dpkg::Options::='force-confdef' -o Dpkg::Options::='force-confold' linux-generic"
      register: install_chk

  - name: autoremove linux-generic
    when: install_chk.rc == 0
      command: "apt-get -y autoremove -o Dpkg::Options::='force-confdef' -o Dpkg::Options::='force-confold'"
      register: auto_chk
```

Comment: I originally started with a very simple playbook like this for updating hosts but found cache was not being updated and many updates were being missed. I added `update_cache` but then found old kernels were not being removed so added `autoremove: yes`. Then found that I needed to select `upgrade: dist` or `upgrade: full` to actually get what I want. There were many corner cases like this and got me to where I am today with this stupidly complex playbook for updating all my hosts. To answer your question, yes, a simple play like what you suggest *should* work but in practice it does not.

Comment: Understood. I have edited my initial answer to reflect your specific ansible syntax error.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I had to un-indent `command` and `register` (as well as the space leading your first `when`) but then this works great. I spent the morning upgrading all kernels so have nothing to test on now but it is running without errors so this will be a great start for next upgrade.